# How to check if a property of a class has thrown an exception

Tags: c#, exception

How can I check if a getter/setter of a property in a class, has thrown an exception? (Before accessing it)

**Example**

For example in this picture, the `ExitTime` property of a process threw an exception of type `System.InvalidOperationException`

[image]

If I use `process.ExitTime`, I get another runtime exception: `No process is associated with this object.`

Comment: Good question. I've had Properties that have caused exceptions, especially if a Property that is also a Factory (Get Property creates an instance if it doesn't already exist). In that case, I never get an error, and it can be hard to track down.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Technically it *hasn't* thrown an exception before you use the accessor method. The only reason that window shows it is because *it tried to get the property*.

So you can't detect this. All you can do is wrap the accessing code in a `try/catch` block to catch the exception when it is thrown.